# Add bpmn:Resource in propertiesPanel

Tags: bpmn.io

Is it possible to add "bpmn:Resource" element in propertiesPanel and edit its attribute? how to do it?

I've already added some properties to property panel based on the property-panel[link] example.

But I have a challenge in adding 'bpmn:Resource' to the properties panel. I don't want it to be added as an `extensionElement`.

I'd like it to be inside `bpmn:Definitions` (beside `bpmn:Process`). Also I'd like to extend the original `bpmn:Resource` to add some parameters.

So in MyModdle.json I added:

```
{
  "name": "Resource",
  "extends": [
    "bpmn:Resource"
  ],
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "parameters",
      "isMany": true,
      "type": "MyParameter"
    }
  ]
},  {
  "name": "MyParameter",
  "properties": [        
    {
      "name": "myParameterType",
      "isAttr": true,
      "type": "String"
    }
    {
      "name": "myParameterName",
      "isAttr": true,
      "type": "String"
    },        
    {
      "name": "myParameterValue",
      "isAttr": true,
      "type": "String"
    }
  ]
}
```

now for example in `newElement` function of MyResource.js

```
var newElement = function (type, prop, factory) {

        return function (element, extensionElements, value) {

            var commands = [];

            var resource = getResource(element);
            if (!resource) {
                var parent = extensionElements;
                resource = createResource(parent, bpmnFactory);
                console.log('resource', resource);
                commands.push(cmdHelper.addAndRemoveElementsFromList(
                    element,
                    extensionElements,
                    'values',
                    'extensionElements',
                    [resource],
                    []
                ));
            }

            var newElem = createResourceParameter(type, resource, bpmnFactory, {
                resourceId: 'id-' + value
            });

    commands.push(cmdHelper.addElementsTolist(element, parameters, prop, [newElem]));
            return commands;
        };
    }
```

I know this cmdHelper adds 'bpmn:Resource' to `extensionElements` but I don't know what to use instead!

Comment: Can you share the full and exact error message?

Comment: Do you mean resource as an attribute? Or do you want to create a custom element with the type `Resource`?

Comment: @NicoHaase I updated my question

Comment: @Jankapunkt I updated my question

Comment: Thank you. I will try to reproduce your problem and give you a proper response.

Comment: I came to a point where I am also stuck -> You wrote: " Also I'd like to extend the original `bpmn:Resource` to add some parameters." But I never found this element in the original bpmn-moddel. Can you show me the documentation on the original resource element?